Firestore executing multiple batch writes or transactions and one of them fails?
Since there is a 500 document limit for Firestore batchWrites and transactions. And to workaround/solve the issue of modifying let's say 1500 documents, I have to run 3 batchWrites/transactions.
What if one of the 3 transactions fails? What happens?

transaction/batchWrite 1, 1 - 500 documents (success)
transaction/batchWrite 2, 501 - 1000 documents (fail)
transaction/batchWrite 3, 1001 - 1500 documents (success)

What is the result?,
1 - 500 newData,
501 - 1000 oldData, 
1001 - 1500 newData

or
1 - 500 newData,
501 - 1000 newData, 
1001 - 1500 newData

I'm currently using the Flutter mobile SDK. Will there be a difference if execute this with a CloudFunction?
I read the Firestore documentation on [Serializable isolation])https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/transaction-data-contention#serializable_isolation), but I do not really understand.

Data contention between transactions is closely related to database isolation levels. A database's isolation level describes how well the system handles conflicts between concurrent operations. Conflict comes from the following database requirements:

Transactions require accurate, consistent data.

To efficiently use resources, databases execute operations concurrently.


In systems with a low isolation level, a read operation within a transaction might read inaccurate data from uncommitted changes in a concurrent operation.
Serializable isolation defines the highest isolation level. Serializable isolation means that:

You can assume that the database executes transactions in series.

Transactions are not affected by uncommitted changes in concurrent operations.


This guarantee must hold even while the database executes multiple transactions in parallel. The database must implement concurrency controls to resolve conflicts that would break this guarantee.
Cloud Firestore guarantees serializable isolation of transactions. Transactions in Cloud Firestore are serialized and isolated by commit time.

Does this mean that it is either all transactions success or all transactions rollback?

Separate transactions have no effect on each other. So if transaction 2 fails, transaction 1 and 3 may still be complete - unless your own application code does something to prevent that.
There is no difference if you do this with a server-side SDK, as there is also a limit on transaction size for those.
How to do this (and whether it is even possible) depends 100% on your use-case, but it typically involves tracking per document or per batch whether they've been processed.

Update You added a long quote from the documentation, and then asked:

Does this mean that it is either all transactions success or all transactions rollback?

Nope, it does not mean that. It only means that transactions are fully isolated, so that transaction 1, 2, and 3 do not see any of the in-progress changes of the other transactions. It does not mean that the transactions all succeed or fail jointly. That also doesn't make sense, as that effectively would mean there is no limit to the in-progress transaction size.

Sorry @Frank I have just edited my question regarding what I have found in the Firestore documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/transaction-data-contention#serializable_isolation
